# How to splice multiple JPEG images together efficiently？

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg

JPEG is decoded by 8*8 blocks. Can the uncompressed data be directly spliced by numpy in rows or columns to form a large picture? If so, the splicing speed can be very fast.

Comment: It's not always 8x8, if there's chroma subsampling applied it could be different.

Comment: Can a group of images with exactly the same compression method be spliced into a large image, just like BMP format.

Comment: I'm not sure or I would have left an answer.  I do know the JPEG format is quite complex, there's nothing by itself in numpy that could handle it.